# AS3IsoLib Importing interface error 1046

Tags: actionscript-3, interface, flash-cs5

I am trying to get started with AS3IsoLib by following in Flash CS5. I am following Lee Brimelow's Flex tutorial on gotoandlearn.com, but have run into a import problem. It is coming from inside AS3IsoLib. In the **Node.as** class, it is throwing *1046:Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: INode.*

```
ActionScript\as3isolib\data\Node.as, Line 246   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: INode.
ActionScript\as3isolib\data\Node.as, Line 246   1120: Access of undefined property INode.
ActionScript\as3isolib\data\Node.as, Line 246   1120: Access of undefined property INode.
ActionScript\as3isolib\data\Node.as, Line 442   1120: Access of undefined property INode.
ActionScript\as3isolib\data\Node.as, Line 32    1172: Definition __AS3__.vec:Vector could not be found.
```

1. Tried using the files from the SVN. Got the 1046 Error. Thinking that the SVN files were the cause
2. I downloaded the .zip file. Same exact 1046 Error
3. I thought it was an import issue, but they share the same package and the Node.as class was successfully found.
4. Maybe it was the location of ActionScript folder where I keep my libraries at. But I have always used it with no problems from Greensock, NResponder, and Papervision3D.

I am stumped, and the only thing I can think of is if it because I am using Flash CS5, and not Flex. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Rob

Here are the imports of each class:

**Node.as**

```
package as3isolib.data
{
import __AS3__.vec.Vector;

import as3isolib.core.as3isolib_internal;
import as3isolib.events.IsoEvent;

import eDpLib.events.EventDispatcherProxy;
import as3isolib.data.INode;

use namespace as3isolib_internal;


public class Node extends EventDispatcherProxy implements INode
{

    public function Node()
    {
        super();
    }
```

**INode.as**

```
package as3isolib.data
{
import eDpLib.events.IEventDispatcherProxy;

public interface INode extends IEventDispatcherProxy
{
```

Comment: I used my copy of Flash Builder 4 and it works. No problems at all or runtime errors. This will be a good reason to learn FB4.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the as3isolib with Flash Builder 4, and it works fine. Granted, Flash Builder 4 is what Lee Brimelow was using in the tutorial.